# Display [object HTMLElement] as HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-directive

I have a directive, and I am trying to change the innerHTML of an HTMLobject.

```js
let icon: HTMLElement;
let attribute = document.createAttribute('icon');
icon = document.createElement('fa-icon');
attribute.value = "home";
icon.setAttributeNode(attribute);
 
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = icon;
```

It does work, but when I see the changes it always displays  *[object HTMLElement]* instead of the html that should be a fontAwesome icon.

What am I doing wrong and how would I insert the icon variable?

Comment: You not developing the Angular way. We don't usually do DOM manipulation like this in Angular, we build components that generate the required DOM elements. If you expand your question with your use case I might be able to explain how you would build a component for what you need.

Comment: I am using the NGx-datatable library, the table is filled with numeric values, I need to add an icon if the succesor value is bigger than the previous value. Most of my trouble come from using this library.

Comment: Take a look at the table component in my library ngx-ez, it is not documented well but passing in templates is easy. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fusers%2Fusers.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = icon;`, you are actually setting the `innerHTML` to the element object instead of adding the element as a child. You have to instead clear the `innerHTML` of the element and then use `appendChild()` on it.

```js
let icon: HTMLElement;
let attribute = document.createAttribute('icon');
icon = document.createElement('fa-icon');
attribute.value = 'home';
icon.setAttributeNode(attribute);
 
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the innerHTML
this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(icon); // Append the child
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a reference to the element to be able to change it, you can actually just set the `innerHTML` property of the element to the `outerHTML` property of `icon`.

```js
let icon: HTMLElement;
let attribute = document.createAttribute('icon');
icon = document.createElement('fa-icon');
attribute.value = 'home';
icon.setAttributeNode(attribute);
 
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = icon.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks, but when applying your solution, in the inspector, it shows that the icon variable now is displayed, but it simply shows nothing now.

Comment: @AndreGomez I can't think of a reason why that would be happening. Have you tried both solutions? (Assuming that you don't need a reference to `icon`)

Answer (score 0):

[appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) would help.

change

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = icon;
```

to

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(icon);
```